# Access class' std::vector with custum class object in a for loop

Tags: c++

I have a classes like so:

```
#include "B.h"
class A{
public: 
std::vector<B> f[32];
}

#include "C.h"
class B{
public: 
C thing;
}

class C{
public:
void func(arg1);
}
```

And I try to do this in main:

```
int main(){
B test;

for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
test.f[i]->thing.func(arg1);}
}
```

but it doesn't let me. I get an error on "test" object saying `expression must have pointer type`. What does this mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: This definition class B{
public: 
C thing;
} will not compile because the name C is undeclared.

Comment: Obviously I included it, that is not en error. The error described is the only one I've got.

Comment: Where is f in B cass ?

Comment: @yomag1234 There are at least other errors because the class definitions are not ended with semicolons.

Comment: In order to produce such error, `test` should be of type `A` not `B`. And if `test` really is `A`, the you have to think for a while - What type is stored in vector `f`? Is it a pointer type or a class type?

Comment: There are no other errors, I just made a smallest possible example and unintentionally forgot to include a few things.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can define a constant vector size, if you want to do that you can just declare an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector size is not set using subscript operator, you might want to use vector constructor to achieve what you are trying to do. Here is modified version of your code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class C{
public:
void func(int arg1) {}
};
class B{
public: 
C thing;
};
class A{
public: 
std::vector<B> f;
A(): f(std::vector<B>(32)) {}

};




int main() {
A test;

for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
test.f[i].thing.func(i);}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. However, how do I access the functions of 'std::vector' ?

Comment: You can call function on f (std::vector object) like test.f.begin(), test.f.end() etc.

Comment: Great, bout what about the functions like swap(), which needs specific object from the vector to function?

Comment: @yomag1234 I think you misunderstand what swap does. It doesn't swap two elements within a vector, it swaps the entire contents of two different vectors. So f.swap(f2) (or std::swap(f,f2) would put the contents of f2 into f and the contents of f into f2.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Doesn't matter as I don't need it anyway. Thanks again.